# mySql - get related values from table

Tags: php, mysql

OK I'm gonna try to be as clear as I can, but bear with me - its been a long week :)

We have a table that is structured like below:

```
+----+----------+---------+------------------+
| id | field_id | user_id |      value       |
+----+----------+---------+------------------+
|  1 | Country  |       2 | USA              |
|  2 | Country  |       3 | USA              |
|  3 | Country  |       4 | CA               |
|  4 | Country  |       5 | MX               |
|  5 | Province |       2 | FL               |
|  6 | Province |       3 | GA               |
|  7 | Province |       4 | British Columbia |
|  8 | Province |       5 | Sonara           |
|  9 | City     |       2 | Orlando          |
| 10 | City     |       3 | Brunswick        |
| 11 | City     |       4 | Vancouver        |
| 12 | City     |       5 | Nogalas          |
+----+----------+---------+------------------+`
```

and we are needing (hoping for) a query to return all Country - State/Province - City combinations for the purpose of dynamically generating a JSON file.

Something to the effect of

```
"SELECT all Provinces and Cities WHERE Country = 'USA'"
```

(but of course, with the structure of our db table - which unfortunately can't be changed - its quite a bit more complicated.

Any of the values that share a common "user_id" can safely be assumed to "go together" (ie. user_id 2 has "USA" for "Country", "FL" for "Province", and "Orlando" for "City").

The end result we are attempting to create a json file similar to the one below.

```
{
"USA": {
    "Florida": [
        {"City": "Orlando"},
        {"City": "Palm Beach"}
    ],
    "Georgia": [
        {"City": "Atlanta"},
        {"City": "Brunswick"}
    ]
}, 
"Canada": {
    "Alberta": [
        {"City": "Calgary"}
    ],
    "Ontario": [
        {"City": "Atlanta"},
        {"City": "Brunswick"}
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: by posting your table as an image you are being the exact opposite of being as clear as possible. Please post the table as text and also some sample rows as text

Comment: Good point, e4c5. One sec...

Comment: edited my original question to remove the image and add the table structure as code.

Comment: thanks for updating the question, but what you are trying is an impossibility with this table. Because it does not define any relationships between states / provines /cities

Comment: I was kinda afraid of that; I was hoping there was an outside chance the user_id could somehow be used to define that relationship, but I guess that was wishful thinking.

Comment: Some observations: This is an EAV model. id serves no purpose here. Instead, you have a perfectly serviceable PRIMARY KEY on the Entity (user_id), and the Attribute (field_id). The problem that arises is that you have nothing that explains that a state, say, is the same kind of thing as a 'province'. But we can work with that. e4c5 is too forlorn in their assertion- ironic given the nature of the Sicilian Defence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the result of this query and some loop you should be able to generate your Json as you want

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04c67/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `field_id` varchar(8), `user_id` int, `value` varchar(16))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `field_id`, `user_id`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Country', 2, 'USA'),
    (2, 'Country', 3, 'USA'),
    (3, 'Country', 4, 'CA'),
    (4, 'Country', 5, 'MX'),
    (5, 'Province', 2, 'FL'),
    (6, 'Province', 3, 'GA'),
    (7, 'Province', 4, 'British Columbia'),
    (8, 'Province', 5, 'Sonara'),
    (9, 'City', 2, 'Orlando'),
    (10, 'City', 3, 'Brunswick'),
    (11, 'City', 4, 'Vancouver'),
    (12, 'City', 5, 'Nogalas')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    tc.`value` as Country,  
    tp.`value` as Province,  
    tcy.`value` as City
FROM (
        SELECT `value`, user_id FROM t WHERE field_id = "Country"
    ) as tc
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT `value`, user_id FROM t WHERE field_id = "Province"
        ) as tp
        ON tc.user_id = tp.user_id
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT `value`, user_id FROM t WHERE field_id = "City"
        ) as tcy
        ON tp.user_id = tcy.user_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04c67/2/0)**:

```
|Country|         Province |      City |
|-------|------------------|-----------|
|   USA |               FL |   Orlando |
|   USA |               GA | Brunswick |
|    CA | British Columbia | Vancouver |
|    MX |           Sonara |   Nogalas |
```

Comment: This is actually... brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: @user2614806 you're welcome! ; BTW, if you want only one line for every city (2 users or more in same city), you can switch the `SELECT` for a `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: I can't seem to get the DISTINCT aspect to work on this query. No matter where I place the DISTINCT, I still get duplicates. What I'd love to be able to do is tweak the query to return distinct Countries or Provinces or States depending on where I place the DISTINCT.

Comment: @user2614806 you probably don't understand the use of `disctinct`, look a the two results at the bottom http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/785246/2 ; I don't really understand what you want to do with countries/provinces/states, make a new question with example and send me the link here